# JNI: how are you meant to handle FindClass failures?

Tags: java, exception, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault

I have a JNI library that executes *many* blocks of code like this on load:

```
jclass id_Collection = global_ref_to_class(env, "java/util/Collection");
jmethodID id_Collection_add = env->GetMethodID(ids.Collection, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
jmethodID id_Collection_iterator = env->GetMethodID(ids.Collection, "iterator", "()Ljava/util/Iterator;");
```

where `global_ref_to_class` is a helper function wrapping `env->FindClass`:

```
jclass global_ref_to_class(JNIEnv* env, string name) {
    jclass class_id = env->FindClass(name.c_str());

    // We need to store a Java 'global reference' to the class to stop it being moved.
    jclass result = static_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(class_id));
    env->DeleteLocalRef(class_id);

    return result;
}
```

Now, the problem happens when `env->FindClass` fails. In particular:

**When the runtime cannot find the java standard library, the subsequent call to `env->GetMethodID` causes a segfault**.

None of the code samples I can find on the net handle this case. Am I meant to go through each block and modify to

```
jclass id_Collection = global_ref_to_class(env, "java/util/Collection");
if(id_Collection != NULL) {
    jmethodID id_Collection_add = env->GetMethodID(ids.Collection, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
    jmethodID id_Collection_iterator = env->GetMethodID(ids.Collection, "iterator", "()Ljava/util/Iterator;");
}
```

? This feels very clunky...

To help people search for this: the error can be EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, SIGSEGV, depending on the system.

Comment: Yes,of course you are: you have to handle all possible errors very carefully in JNI. But why write this piece of JNI at all? It's just `Class.forName()` plus an unnecessary `NewGlobalRef()`. Do it directly in Java. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Because "The top five performance pitfalls for programmers using JNI are:

Not caching method IDs, field IDs, and classes".  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jni/#notc

Comment: BTW, I have no idea what you mean by "do it directly in Java"... the native methods I am writing need to return Java objects like Iterators.  The only way to do this is using JNI methods like CallVoidMethod . Those need class and method IDs. Those need to be cached.

Comment: If you look at e.g. https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html (or many other code samples on the web) you will find that the NULL is not trapped.

Comment: You should of course check the return value (and Java exception status) for any JNI call that could return an error or throw an exception. It's not that much work to place all these checks in a re-usable class or function.

Comment: "Clunky", yes, that's C. As for handling them, throw an exception—unless FindClass fails to find the exception class.